# Bigquery GQL support

Tags: google-bigquery

Is GQL support planned in BigQuery? If not why not? 
I know you can use an SQL-like language on a browser or command-line tool, but it doesn't make sense to me that you can't use this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want from GQL that is not supported in BigQuery? The only differences between BigQuery and GQL syntax are support for additional datatypes (which aren't in BigQuery) and appengine key support, which doesn't make sense in BigQuery.

And you certainly can use BigQuery programatically. [This](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/hello_bigquery_api) page shows how to acccess BigQuery from java. If java isn't your favorite language, there are client libraries for several other languages or you can code against the raw REST-ful HTTP interface.

If you give a better idea of the problem you're trying to solve, we can give a better idea of how to help and whether it will be supported in BigQuery.

Comment: I was referring to programmatic SQL-like querying. I'm aware of the REST interface.

Comment: The REST interface simply takes a SQL query inside of a job JSON object. Results are returned asynchronously or synchronously depending on your choice of jobs.insert or jobs.query. Will this provide the programmatic access you desire?

Comment: Thanks Ryan that's exactly what I needed. Must have missed it in the documenation.